# Aws Model Quality Monitoring without Endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio, amazon-sagemaker-clarify

Is there any possible ways to do model monitoring in aws without an endpoint? Kindly share any good notebook regarding this if you knew

Aws not gives any explainable example regarding Batch Model monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SageMaker Model Monitor monitors the quality of Amazon SageMaker machine learning models in production.

You can set up continuous monitoring with a real-time endpoint (or a batch transform job that runs regularly), or on-schedule monitoring for asynchronous batch transform jobs.

Here are some example notebooks:

(1) SageMaker Model Monitor with Batch Transform - Data Quality Monitoring On-Schedule ([link](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/61f5a7b50c4c7680815d7f81c145f7ba1d70c02f/sagemaker_model_monitor/model_monitor_batch_transform/SageMaker-ModelMonitoring-Batch-Transform-Data-Quality-On-schedule.ipynb))

(2) SageMaker Data Quality Model Monitor for Batch Transform with SageMaker Pipelines On-demand ([link](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/61f5a7b50c4c7680815d7f81c145f7ba1d70c02f/sagemaker_model_monitor/model_monitor_batch_transform/SageMaker-ModelMonitoring-Batch-Transform-Data-Quality-With-SageMaker-Pipelines-On-Demand.ipynb))

Comment: How can i visualize violations reports in form of graphs on sagemaker studio from batch transform monitoring job reports same like endpoint?